# Manually calling DataBindingContext.updateModels() causes UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface

I am updating an RCP application from 2015 to 2018-09 (last version that supports a 32-bit JVM).

On a managed form with multiple sections each with their own `DataBindingConext` (dbc), I keep track of all validation errors and warning messages using an `AggregateValidationStatus` in the master dbc.

At one point in the user flow, I need to present a list of all validation error and warning messages.  When I originally wrote the code in 2015, I wanted to be *sure* all the validation code had executed prior to displaying to the user, so I manually called `masterDbc.updateModels()`.  This executed without exceptions.

Now manually calling `masterDbc.updateModels()` causes an `UnsupportedOperationException` on the return of `AggregateValidationStatus.calculate()`.  Note this exception happens when manually calling `updateModels()` on any dbc, not just the master dbc.

Two questions:

1. Is this expected behavior?
2. Given that the user has to choose a menu option / button to get the summary of validation issues, do I need to call updateModels() manually?

Thanks,
Timothy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the issue is to pass in a targetToModel `UpdateValueStrategy` with `POLICY_NEVER` so that no attempt to update the read only `AggregateValidationStatus` is made.

```
this.dbc.bindValue(WidgetProperties.text().observe(lblErrMsg),
    new AggregateValidationStatus(this.dbc, AggregateValidationStatus.MAX_SEVERITY),
                new UpdateValueStrategy(UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_NEVER), null);
```